# How to read char by char in c++ until new line

Tags: c++

is there any way of reading 3 (or any quantity) strings char by char (in a loop where i can access the exact char that is being read)?

For this input:

```
banana
apple
orange
```

I tried to do a loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  while(cin.peek() != '\n') {
    char aux;
    cin >> aux;
  }
}
```

But it occurs that this read the first string as `banana` and the "doesn't read anymore".

If I tried to print the strings formed by the chars I receive

```
banana
banana
banana
```

Comment: This is the classic [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  For what reason and purpose do you want to do this?  What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: Once you hit `\n` this `cin.peek() != '\n'` is always false. You could add an additional loop after the while loop to consume characters until there's not a `\n`.

Comment: Why not `std::getline()`?

Comment: Hello @PaulMcKenzie, I'm trying to solve the problem [Helping Fill Bates](https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=1508). The problem require to check if a sequence of chars occurs in a string. I'm tryng to read char by char, because i think this way I can save time. But i'm new at c++, and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: *"If I tried to print the strings formed by the chars"* -- since this is the observable symptom of your issue, the code to do this should be in your [mre].

Comment: What is your definition of "save time"?  Surely the best way to save time (in terms of coding effort) is to use `std::getline`, `std::string` and the various string searching functions available in the standard library.  And if you're worried about time (in terms of performance) then don't be -- that's the last thing you should be thinking about when you are struggling to write and debug a few lines of simple I/O code.

Comment: @paddy i'm trying to solve the problem, I linked above. There I have to read one main string, and others n "smaller" strings. When i said save time, i mean, try to resolve the problem while reading the chars of  the "smallers" strings, instead of read each as a string with `getline` or `cin >> smaller_string` and then proccess it to find the solution. All other logic code seens allright, i just have this problem to read the input. I know it's "simple I/O code" but I tried and searched and I haven't found one solution to this, then I asked here.

Comment: @RheidneAchiles *The problem require to check if a sequence of chars occurs in a string.* -- `bool doesSequenceOccur(std::string data, std::string searchSequence);` -- If you're not doing this, you are approaching the whole thing upside-down.  Who cares *how* the string comes in?  Just get the string, feed it to that function, and have the logic inside that function return either `true` or `false`.  Right now, you're struggling with the least important part of that entire problem.

Comment: @RheidneAchiles I think the point was opting for simple is *nearly always* preferred to the root of all evil: premature optimization. You harbor only speculation that reading data from `std::cin` one character at a time will offer any performance boost whatsoever, while using `std::getline(std::cin, somstr)`, then iterating the resulting string will not only solve the *real* problem (the problem from UVAOLJ), but dramatically simplify the solution itself. Considering the entire line must be read anyway to advance to the next query string, set aside the evil and code something that works first.

Comment: That said, RetiredNinja told you what was wrong with the loop you're attempting on the second comment above. if, for whatever reason, you want to pursue this lnie, that obviously needs to be addressed.

Comment: @RheidneAchiles Imagine if this were a school assignment, and you had 10 days to complete the problem.   Let's say you wasted 9 and a half-days trying to solve this unimportant riddle of reading char by char, instead of just simply reading the entire line in one shot.  Then you now have a half-day to actually solve the *real* problem, and that is determining whether the search string is part of the original string.  So what is "wasting time"?  You trying to do some odd input routines seems to be what is the time wasting part of the whole problem.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I already had all the logic done. Today i only change this part of reading char by char to read the string with `cin >> some_string` method, and then I did all the process I was already doing. It worked and passed in the judge time. Thanks you all. I still think that would be nice to have an answer for this question, since it can help others tying to do the same. The answer below seems to work right. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, the problem is that `cin.peek` looks at the next char but does not read it, at the same time when trying to go to the next loop iteration `cin.peek` was pouring on the same character as last time, respectively, it will look at '\n'. To avoid this, just add a single character reading after the end of the internal loop. Also, if your input data set can end without a new line char, you should add a check for it (in the example, I added a check for this, but if you do not need it, you can leave the inner loop unchanged)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    char aux;
    while(std::cin.peek() != '\n' && std::cin >> aux) {
        //do whatever you want
    }
    std::cin.get(); //this is required
}
```